# gazebo with player

Tags: installation

I guess gazebo is more often being used with ROS and as standalone, has anyone tried to use gazebo ( version 1.0 and above) with player ? I am cool using gazebo with ROS (Electric) and also as standalone but have never done well with the installation with player. Any first hand experience may be useful. Which version of player to use with gazebo (version 1.0 and above) ? Also, is it advisable to use gazebo with player as player has not been a very active project for nearly the last 2 years (last version release (3.0.2) was in July 2010) ?

I had asked a similar question at gazebo-list@kforge.ros.org, however I hope to reach more people at answers.gazebosim.org.

---

#### Original comments:

**Comment by** [Arkapravo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/11/arkapravo/) on 2012-09-22 00:41:52.641179-05:00:

@nkoenig Yo ! I felt the same ! I will be using ROS - ROS is a big improvement on player.

#### End of original comments

---

> [image: Gazebo Answers logo]
>
> [Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/10/gazebo-with-player/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/11/arkapravo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-20 06:11:04.609245 UTC
>
> Post score: 0

---

---JSON_START_ROS2022_SE_MIGRATION {'name': 'Arkapravo', 'score': 0, 'timestamp': '2012-09-20 06:11:04.609245 UTC', 'user_id': 11}---

Answer (score 0):

There is limited support for Player within Gazebo. I believe it consists of position, camera, and laser plugins.

I haven't used Player in many years. But I think the latest version should work with Gazebo.

In short, I would recommend using ROS.

---

> [image: Gazebo Answers logo]
>
> Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7661 on 2012-09-21 19:33:46.650602 UTC
>
> This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site
>
> Post score: 0

---

---JSON_START_ROS2022_SE_MIGRATION {'accepted': True, 'name': 'nkoenig', 'score': 0, 'timestamp': '2012-09-21 19:33:46.650602 UTC', 'user_id': 5}---